# Integrating third party async libraries with NodeJS

Tags: c++, node.js, asynchronous, v8, libuv

How do I implement Node JS addon with asnyc third part library.
I am able to implement synchronous functions but when it comes to asynchronous functions not sure how exactly it works. Should it be invoked from main loop or it should be in async_work.

The scenario is similar to example explained in http://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/threads.html#inter-thread-communication but instead of downloading in async_work, I want to invoke asynchronous function which takes care of downloading.

Example async function : download(url, callback);

Sample Code:

```
Handle<Value> DNS::Download(const Arguments& args) {
    HandleScope scope;
    uv_loop_t *loop = uv_default_loop();
    uv_async_t *uv_async_req = new uv_async_t;
    uv_work_t *uv_work_req = new uv_work_t;

    AsyncData *asyncData = new AsyncData;
    asyncData->url = "http://..../";

    uv_async_req->data = asyncData;
    uv_work_req->data = asyncData;

    uv_async_init(loop, uv_async_req, send_progress);
    uv_queue_work(loop, uv_work_req, initiate_download, after);

    //Not sure if i have to invoke download(url, callback); here itself
    //or in fake_download

    return scope.Close(Undefined());
}

void send_progress(uv_async_t *handle, int status /*UNUSED*/) {
    AsyncData *asyncData = (AsyncData*)handle->data;
    Handle<Value> values[] = {};
    //Invoking js callback function.
    asyncData->callback->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), 0, values);
}

void initiate_download(uv_work_t *req) {
    //I would like to invoke non blocking async function here
    download(url, callback);
}

void callback(status, size) {
    //Send event to the send_progress
    uv_async_send(&async);
}
```

My call back is not getting invoked at all in both the cases(Invoking in main thread or in async_work.) and JavaScript keeps waiting for the callback.

Any examples are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: uv_queue_work runs the given function in libuv's internal thread pool, which is quite limited and shared with fs and dns operations, I wouldn't run lots of stuff in there.